# Primeng Date Navigator Value Change

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

In my Primeng DatePicker I have used

`[monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="2017:2030"`

But the problem is:

if we click on `<` button after selecting `January` and `2017` from navigator it doesn't move to `December 2016` as displayed in the PrimeNg demo for `Navigators`. In stead it goes to year `2030` i.e last year of year range.

I'd  like to make it like this:
 if we click `<` when navigator in `Jan 2017`, it will load previous set of years i.e. `2003 to 2016` in navigator.

Could you please guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug from primeng! this issue will resolve if you downgrade the plugin to 5.2.0 version.

so the newer(after 5.2.0) versions only has this issue. :)
and no much update from plugin side :(